# Prove that $||x-y||·||x+y|| < ||x||^2+||y||^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

I have a doubt to prove this exercise:

$$||x-y||·||x+y|| < ||x||^2+||y||^2 \;\;\;\;\; \forall\; x,y \in R^n$$

What I've done:

$$||x-y||·||x+y|| = \sqrt{(x-y,x-y)(x+y,x+y)} = \sqrt{((x,x)+(-y,-y))((x,x)+(y,y)}) = \sqrt{((x,x)+(y,y))^2} = (x,x)+(y,y) = ||x||^2+||y||^2$$

But then, $||x-y||·||x+y|| = ||x||^2+||y||^2$, not $<$.

Why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your computation is wrong. You seem to presume that $x,y$ are orthogonal.

Comment: But one of the dot product's properties stated that: $(\alpha x + \beta y,z) = \alpha (x,z) + \beta (y,z)$, which I've applied on the proof.

Comment: Your attempt contains so much fundamental flaws that I believe you should revise some material....

Comment: Try computing $\|x-y\|^2= \langle x-y,x-y \rangle $ again. There are four terms. You have only two. Just do the work.

Comment: Note that the vector norm $\|x\|$ is typed `\| x\|` in LaTeX, not $|| x ||$. Note the difference in spacing, which makes more complicated expression more readable. E.g., comparing $\big|\|a\|\|b\|\big|$ versus $\big|||a||||b||\big|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do it by parts. To start with, we have

\begin{align*}
\lVert x-y\rVert^{2} = \langle x - y,x - y\rangle = \lVert x\rVert^{2} - 2\langle x,y\rangle + \lVert y\rVert^{2}
\end{align*}
Analogously,
\begin{align*}
\lVert x+y\rVert^{2}= \langle x + y,x + y\rangle = \lVert x\rVert^{2} + 2\langle x,y\rangle + \lVert y\rVert^{2}
\end{align*}
which implies that
\begin{align*}
\lVert x-y\rVert^{2}\times\lVert x+y\rVert^{2} = (\lVert x\rVert^{2} + \lVert y\rVert^{2})^{2} - 4\langle x,y\rangle^{2} \leq (\lVert x\rVert^{2} + \lVert y\rVert^{2})^{2} 
\end{align*}
from whence the result holds.